# Полоса прокрутки появляется внизу веб-страницы

Tags: html, css, jquery, стилизация

У меня есть страница, и я не могу понять, почему появляется нижняя полоса прокрутки навигации. [эксель-обучение.рф](https://xn----btbkcarjjvh3a3a6c9ck.xn--p1ai) Кажется, что какой-то элемент за кадром, но я не могу понять, что! Решение приветствуется! Спасибо

Comment: В разделе "Как проходит обучение" есть блок с видео, который выезжает справа. Добавьте родительской секции свойство `overflow: hidden`, и полоса перестанет появляться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в элементах `.btn`, у которых в бутстрапе по умолчанию задан `white-space: nowrap;` В какой-то момент эти элементы начинают выползать за края экрана. Нужно переопределить это свойство на `white-space: normal;`, чтобы текст переносился на новую строку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо огромное, помогло, подскажите пожалуйста, как так вы с ходу нашли в чем проблема?

Comment: @АлексейСоболев, открыл отладчик, уменьшил окно браузера до размера, когда появляется скролл, и просто посмотрел, что вылезает наружу - никакой магии :) На скрине всё видно

Comment: Спасибо еще раз за помощь!